# Jquery adds selector and fades in but fades out the entire header

Tags: jquery

Basically, I have my header navigation I want to fade in once the user scrolls down past a certain point. Here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu1yLe4u/37/).

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('#main').addClass('appear');
        $('#main').fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        $('#main').removeClass('appear');
        $('#main').fadeOut(1000);
    }
});
```

The problems I'm having are

1. It's fading out the original header even if I change the fadeOut to use appear instead.
2. Once the animation is done and it fades away style `display:none` is added and the content jumps up.

Comment: Use `$('#main').animate({'opacity':0})` instead of fade out, and vise versa for fade in, this will solve the display:none problem

Comment: Thank you for the comment. When I add that it's like having no fade in or fade out function since I have it    position:fixed anyway. I really fail to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: If you use a callback when the fadeOut has finished to remove the class, this will solve the content from jumping up. i.e. `$('#main').fadeOut(1000, function(){
      $('#main').removeClass('appear');
    });`

Comment: Wow thanks that worked great! Only problem now is when I scroll back up my original header bar never reappears. Shouldn't I be targeting appear since that is the one that is suppose to fade in and out? `$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
 $('#main').addClass('appear');
 $('.appear').fadeIn(1000);
 }
 else{
 $('.appear').fadeOut(1000, function(){ $('#main').removeClass('appear'); });
 }
 
 });`  this still has the same effect however and my original header never returns. Tried adding in another fade in for just the #main and just stuck on an endlessloop

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample snippet which does the job

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
/*added one more condition(hasClass) because once document scrollTop > 150 this condition will be success again and again but at first we add fixed class so checking this this will avoid this problem*/
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150 && !$('header').hasClass('fixed')) 
{ 
/*here stop will stop any on going animation
first set oppacity to 0 (.css('opa...)) then add fixed class and start animation from 0 to 1
*/     $('header').stop().css('opacity',0).addClass('fixed').animate({opacity:1});
}
/*when document scrolled back to top (<150) and have the fixed class we added earlier an aditional condition which checks if an animation is not ongoing*/
if ($(document).scrollTop() < 150 && $('header').hasClass('fixed') && !$('header').is(':animated'))
{
/*animate opacity to 0, in the animation complete callback set the opacity to 1 and remove fixed class this will make the beg header to appear again when scrolled to top*/
  $('header').stop().animate({opacity:0},function(){
   $(this).css('opacity','1').removeClass('fixed');
  });
}

});
```

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #d6e0ae;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
 Header of this page
</header>

<div>Blank contents to make a big scroll </div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to this with jquery only as it's my first snippet I've ever made on my own. I'm sure there is just something missing to make the header reappear, I will have to look around for a fix. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok i removed css animation and added jquery animation, check the edited answer

Comment: How can I achieve the same effect with my code? Please I'm trying to understand what I'm specifically doing wrong and why it's not working so I can learn.

Comment: What we both do is same your #main is my header and appear is my fixed class, now i will comment my code then you may understand

Comment: Hope you understand what I did